# What is the expected number of coin tosses needed to obtain a head?

Tags: probability, expectation

Due to my recent misunderstandings regarding the 'expected value' concept I decided to post this question. Although I have easily found the answer on the internet I haven't managed to fully understand it.

I understood that the formula for the expected value is:

$$E(x) = x_1p_1 +x_2*p_2 +...+x_np_n$$

The x's are the possible value that the random variable can take and the p's are the probabilites that this certain value is taken.

So, if I get a head on the first try, then  $ p_1 = \frac{1}{2} , x_1 = 1 $
If I get a head on the second try, then $ p_2 = \frac{1}{4} , x_2 = 2 $

And then, I woudl have that:

$$E(x) = \frac{1}{2}1+ \frac{1}{4}2 +...$$

So my reasoning led me to an inifnite sum which I don't think I can't evaluate it that easy. In the 'standard' solution of this problem, the expected value is found in a reccurisve manner. So the case in which the head doesn't appear in the first toss is treated reccursively. I haven't understood that step.

My questions are: is my judgement correct? How about that reccursion step? Could somebody explain it to me?

Comment: For fun, I would say 2. =)

Comment: Yes, I knew that too. :D I just didn't know how we found that answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of tosses, and let $e=E(X)$. It is clear that $e$ is finite.

We might get a head on the first toss. This happens with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and in that case $X=1$.

Or else we might get a tail on the first toss. In that case, we have used up $1$ toss, and we are "starting all over again." So in that case the expected number of **additional** tosses is $e$. More formally, the *conditional expectation* of $X$ *given* that the first toss is a tail is $1+e$.

It follows (Law of Total Expectation) that
$$e=(1)\cdot\frac{1}{2}+(1+e)\cdot\frac{1}{2}.$$

This is a linear equation in $e$. Solve.

**Remark:** The "infinite series" approach gives
$$E(X)=1\cdot\frac{1}{2}+2\cdot\frac{1}{2^2}+3\cdot\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots.$$
This series, and related ones, has been summed repeatedly on MSE.

Comment: Are we allowed to define the problem reccurisvely in this manner? I mean...it seems a little wierd to me to do so.

Comment: Conditioning like I did is a totally standard technique in the calculation of expectation.

Comment: I get that if the coin flip is a tail then the expected number increases, but still, I am not fully convinced..

Comment: So if it is a tail, then X = e + 1...

Comment: Well, perhaps you can use the series approach for general $p$, and the equation $e=p+(1+e)(1-p)$, and see that they give the same answer.

Comment: **Given** that the first toss is a tail, $E(X)=1+e$.

Comment: So. Let's do a short recap. If it is a head! We're done. We have a 1/2 we need to add to our sum. Otherwise...I totally get that the number of expected thwrows increases with 1! But, for me, applying this reccursion formula means that I have already tossed the coin e times....so with a probability of 1/2 I wil need e+1 times...I don't know if you get what I don't understand

Comment: It is not true that with probability $1/2$ you will need $1+e$. What is true is that **given** the first is tail the total expected number of tosses is $1+e$.

Comment: @Bardo Note that in [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910819/meaning-of-expected-value-in-the-following-problem) in my solution we use essentially the same trick (in a slightly more complex situation).

Comment: Apparently I need to give this concept a closer look..I have read and re-read the reccursion of argument dozesn of time..still doesn't ring a bell. Any suggestions for similar problems/good books/articles I could read? It seems to me that I'm a little dumb here

Comment: The method you used it's called ' next step conditioning method' ?

Comment: Related but simpler: There are two paths, left and right, which you take with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$. If you take the left path, your probability of success is $s$. If you take the other path, your probability of success is $b$.  Then your probability of success is $(a)(p)+(b)(1-p)$.

Comment: The method used is called *conditioning* on the first toss. Maybe look at the Wikipedia article on the Law of Total Expectation. Look also at the article on conditional expectation. Much of both articles is complicated, but parts will be helpful.

Comment: Excuse me for prolonging this discussion. So, one path leads me to 'head'. The other leads me to tail. I take each path with a 1/2 probability. I have identified p, and 1 - p which happen to be equal. Excuse me, one of the reasons I might have trouble getting your argument is because I am not a native speaker. So help me out, please. Who is a and b? Yes, I recognize your model, it's a 'tree of events', that's how I call it.

Comment: Yes, it is a tree. I was giving an *analogy* that might be more familiar, though in the discrete case the tree analysis can be extened to expectations. The numbers $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary probabilities.

Comment: And in our case, in our problem what are a and b ?

Comment: It was an *analogy*. One could flesh it out to a full expectation calculation if we were dealing with a finite tree, but it is messy for an infinite tree. For the particular class of tree examples I gave, the expected number of successes is $(a)(p)+(b)(1-p)$.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: I am both amazed and terifyed. The expected value is actually a expected value..So, I know that I expect to toss the coin x times to get a head. If on the first toss I get a head, then I'm done. I need to add 1*(1/2). Then, if I toss a head, because x is an expected value...I EXPECT to throw another x coins until I get a head, plus I need to take into account the 1 toss I made..The argument was right before my eyes all that time. Please, could you validate this for me?

Comment: I am amazed because...the argument was that simple and elegnat. I am terifyed because I need to read a little more careful if I want to really know math..Thank you, @ André. It's the second time you answer a question of mine. Hope you'll help me again. I promise I will be more attentive and I will ask more relevant questions..

Comment: The above is a good intuitive summary.

Comment: Great, so I can say I got it..

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is perfectly fine. The probability of getting the first head in the $n$th trial is $\frac{1}{2^n}$, so we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(x) = \sum_{ n \geq 1} \frac{n}{2^n}.
$$
This infinite sum can be calculated in the following way: first note that
$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n
$
for $|x|<1$. Differentiating both sides yields
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n \geq 0} n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n \geq 1} n x^{n-1} = \frac1x \sum_{n \geq 1} n x^n.
$$
Pluggin in $x = \frac12$ yields $4 = 2 \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n}{2^n} = 2 \mathbb{E}(x)$, or $\mathbb{E}(x) = 2$.

The recursive solution goes, I think, as follows: let $\mathbb{E}(x)$ be the expected number of trials needed. Then the expected number of trials needed after the first trial, given that it was *not* heads, is also $\mathbb{E}(x)$. In other words, the expected (total) number of trials is $\mathbb{E}(x)+1$ in that case. This gives the equation
$$ \mathbb{E}(x) = \frac12 + \frac12(\mathbb{E}(x)+1)$$ 
which gives the same answer $\mathbb{E}(x) = 2$.

Comment: It's good to know that my approach wasn't incorrect, it gives me a little confidence. I am no thinking about that reccursion step.

Answer (score 3):

To make ends meet... You have been explained by several users that, looking at the toss process itself, one sees that the expectation $E(X)$, that you know is $E(X)=S$, with $$S=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{n}{2^n},$$ solves the relation $$E(X)=1+\frac12E(X).$$ It happens that one can also show directly that $$S=1+\frac12S,$$ this relation following from a *shift of indexes*. To do so, note that $S=R+T$ with
$$R=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{1}{2^n},\qquad T=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{n-1}{2^n},
$$
hence, using the change of variable $n=k+1$, $$T=\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac{k}{2^{k+1}}=\frac12\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac{k}{2^k}=\frac12\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{k}{2^k}=\frac12S,$$
hence the proof would be complete if one knew that $$R=1.$$ To show this, use the same trick once again, that is, note that $$R=\frac12+\sum_{n\geqslant2}\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac12+\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac12+\frac12\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}==\frac12+\frac12R,$$ hence the proof that $S=2$ is complete.

Comment: Yes, I got it...I knew beforehand the trick of shifting indexes, so I totatly understood your argument..But I am still struggling to undesrtande the simpler argument..Thank you very much!